# PHP - Imprimir varios registros en fpdf

Tags: php, array, pdf, script, fpdf

Buen día sera que me pueden ayudar les explico,

Estoy tratando de generar un formulario tiene una opción nombre y agregar nombres y eliminar nombres, al mandarlo a FPDF solo me manda me manda el ultimo registro, si pongo 5 o 10 nombres, solo me manda el ultimo registro

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Acá está mi codigo, no conseguí insertarlo acá.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ls-OeQh48b2GU5jKLqNApNkZPo6gIyk1

Por favor su ayuda, muchas gracias :)

Comment: añade el código a la pregunta, selecciónalo y presiona `ctrl  + k` para darle formato

Comment: Lo que pasa es que no me dejo insertarlo, como que se descuadra, pero ya lo subí a G drive https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ls-OeQh48b2GU5jKLqNApNkZPo6gIyk1

Por favor ayudame si puedes! :)

Comment: encontraste solución?